# How to ensure page.type() uses a newline character \n instead of triggering an Enter key

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

The text I inserted has the character `'\n'`, but after using the code `await page.type(element, text, {delay: 50})`, upon encountering the character `'\n'` it automatically uses keyboard <kbd>Enter</kbd>. How can it autofill text with `'\n'`?

Comment: Is this a textarea? Please share a [mcve]. Did you try escaping the newline with a `"\\n"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to escape the newlines: `\\n` instead of `\n`. The below code shows a few strategies you can try, including replacing `\n` with `\\n` in strings outside of your control.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);

  //                      no Enter-+     +- if you _do_ want an Enter
  //                               |     |
  //                              vvv   vv
  await page.type("textarea", "foo\\nbar\nbaz");

  await page.$eval("textarea", el => el.value += "\\n"); // also may be possible

  // or if you can't control the escaping in the literal:
  const unescaped = "xxx\nyyy\nzzz";
  const escaped = unescaped.replace(/\n/g, "\\n");
  await page.type("textarea", escaped);

  await page.screenshot({path: "textarea.png"});
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```